# How to run an entire rspec group from the command line?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I can run a single rspec example with

```
spec -e 'should be awesome' spec/models/stuff_spec.rb
```

but how do I run an entire group ?

```
describe 'GoodStuff' do
  it 'should be awesome' do
    true.should be_true
  end
  it 'want to run this too' do
    true.should be_true
  end
end
```

I've heard there's a spec -g option, but a) its not documented b) it does not work for me on rspec 1.3.0..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spec -l N   # thats minus L where the line number is that of the
describe group..

PPS - I've heard of spec -g 'GoodStuff' - but that doesn't work for me
on rspec 1.3.0